# Posting data and file with Aurelia to ASP.NET webapi

Tags: javascript, c#, file-upload, asp.net-web-api, aurelia

I'm trying to add an input with file upload to my application.

This is my view with two inputs, one text and one file:

```
<template>
  <form class="form-horizontal" submit.delegate="doImport()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputLangName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Language key</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" value.bind="languageKey" class="form-control" id="inputLangName" placeholder="Language key">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputFile" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Upload file</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="inputFile" accept=".xlsx" files.bind="files">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Do import</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>
```

In my webapi I have this code which I copied and pasted from [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2):

```
public class ImportLanguageController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
    {
        // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

        try
        {
            // Read the form data.
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            // This illustrates how to get the file names.
            foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
            {
                //Trace.WriteLine(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
                //Trace.WriteLine("Server file path: " + file.LocalFileName);
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
        }
    }
}
```

At last I have my view model in Aurelia:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {HttpClient, json} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';

@inject(HttpClient)
export class Import {
  languageKey = null;
  files = null;

  constructor(http){
    http.configure(config => {
      config
        .useStandardConfiguration();
    });

    this.http = http;
  }

  doImport() {
    //What goes here??
  }
}
```

So my question is, what logic goes in my function `doImport`? I'm not sure the code in my controller method in the webapi is correct, feel free to have comments on that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should help you get started:

```
doImport() {
  var form = new FormData()
  form.append('language', this.languageKey)
  form.append('file', this.files)
  //Edit, try this if the first line dont work for you
  //form.append('file', this.files[0])

  this.http.fetch('YOUR_URL', {
     method: 'post',
     body: form
  })
  .then( response => { 
     // do whatever here

  });
}
```

Depending on the webapi response you provide (if any) you may want to use following:

```
.then( response => response.json() )
.then( response => {
   // do whatever here
});
```

One thing I should mention too is that fetch uses COR so if you get any CORS error you may need to enable them on the server side.

Here's a gist.run for the Aurelia part (posting won't work unless you change the URL):
https://gist.run/?id=6aa96b19bb75f727271fb061a260f945

Comment: Had to make a small modification `form.append('file', this.files[0])`.

Comment: @John idk y append is not working, at last it gives empty 'form'