# File upload is not working in aurelia js

Tags: content-type, aurelia

I need to upload files in Aurelia Js. I don't know how to send file to server(hit to given API). I have two doubts, one is in my 'content-type' and another one is, do i need to change my image object to any other format. Here is the code i used,

**scanupload.html :**

```
<input type="file"  files.bind="selectedFiles" change.delegate="onSelectFile($event)">
```

**scanupload.js :**

```
 onSelectFile($event){ var myurl = 'http://cdn.dmiapp.tk/file?authToken=bLNYMtfbHntfloXBuGlSzPueilaHtZx&type=jpg&name=testfile.jpg&organizationId=1&userId=7&sourceType=USER_UPLOADS';

    this.httpValueConverter.call_http(myurl,'POST',{file :this.selectedFiles[0]},'fileupload')
        .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    if(data.meta && data.meta.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log('success');
    }
});}
```

**httpservice.js :**

```
 call_http(url,method,myPostData,action,params) {
    return this.httpClient.fetch(url,
                {
                    method: method,
                    body : myPostData,
                    headers : {
                        'authorization': this.authorization,
                        'Content-Type':'form-data'
                    }
                })
                .then(response => response.json());}
```

**Error :** bad request and unsupported media file.
Also tried content type, **form-data** and **multipart/form-data**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Posting data and file with Aurelia to ASP.NET webapi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37589636/posting-data-and-file-with-aurelia-to-asp-net-webapi)

Answer (score 0):

If it's an image your media type must be: "image/jpeg" and you can try to upload the image as a blob.

This does not seem to be an Aurelia-specific issue.

Try first to make a simple example working such as:

[Upload image using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373834/upload-image-using-javascript)

When this works refactor it to an Aurelia view.

Also, verify that you have indeed configured your server to support the necessary mime type.

For multipart/form-data you can look at the following tweaks and packages:

- https://github.com/expressjs/node-multiparty
- https://github.com/expressjs/multer

Comment: tnx @darxtar but in my case, it might be image or doc or any kind of file .

Comment: edited my answer, your issue might be on the server side